# How to pass a value of a row to a radio button using struts and jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, struts

I'm trying to pass data to textfield when I click on a form, but I have difficulty passing a data to a radio button. I'm using struts.

I use this to obtain the data of each element of my form

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<html>

<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="le-frog" locale="es"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //La funcion donde se va ejecutar el evento
    $.subscribe('rowselectVendedor', function(event,data) {

            var id = event.originalEvent.id;


            $('#idSeleccion').attr('value',id);

             var grid = event.originalEvent.grid;
             var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

             document.getElementById("idMantNombre").value = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'nom_pos');
             document.getElementById("idMantApellido").value = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'ape_pos');
             document.getElementById("idMantFecha").value = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'fec_nac');
             document.getElementById("idMantGenero").value = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'gen_pos');
             document.getElementById("idMantEstado").value = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'idEstado');



    });
```

This is my form. I'm using struts tags. It is a crud

```
<s:form id="idForm" >
        <s:hidden id="idSeleccion" name="idSeleccion"/>

        <label id="idMantLabelNombre">Nombre</label>
        <s:textfield   id="idMantNombre"  name="nombre"  />
        <br><br>
        <label id="idMantLabelApellido">Apellido</label>
        <s:textfield id="idMantApellido"  name="apellido"  />
        <br><br>
        <label id="idMantLabelFecha">Fecha</label>
        <sj:datepicker id="idMantFecha" name="fecha"  displayFormat="yy-mm-dd" showOn="focus"/>
        <br><br>
        <label id="idMantLabelGenero">Genero</label>
        <s:radio id="idMantGenero" name="genero" 
                list="#{'Femenino':'Femenino','Masculino':'Masculino'}" headerValue="Femenino"/> 

        <br><br>
        <label id="idMantLabelEstado">Estado Civil</label>          
        <s:url id="codEstado" action="cargarEstado"/>
        <sj:select name="estado" href="%{codEstado}" id="idMantEstado"
                                                        list="lstEstado"
                                                        listKey="idEstado"
                                                        listValue="nomEstado"

                                                        headerKey="-1"
                                                        headerValue="[Seleccione]"/>
        <br><br>
</s:form>
```